# Example open source client-server code projects

Tags: client-server

What are some open source client-server projects which might be best to look at and mimic their code organization style?

Java is preferred but not required.

#### Related:

I'm still trying to determine an answer to my question from a few minutes ago, ["Should client-server code be written in one 'project' or two?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516767/should-client-server-code-be-written-in-one-project-or-two) and I think it would benefit me to see how other projects organize their code (and hopefully deduce the pros and cons of why they chose to do it that way).

Comment: Why aren't you just editing your original question?

Comment: This is an entirely different question. There are other issues besides division of code into one or two projects. I only mentioned the previous question because it was my inspiration for this one.

Comment: @Ricket: Fair enough.  I'm rearranging a bit.  Check my edits and just revert them if you disagree.

Comment: @Carsten: By thin client do you mean a server that utilizes an existing technology such as telnet? I was thinking something with a rich client and server pair.

Comment: Rich client: usually a stand-alone application with at least some internal logic, e.g. gets data from the server, but does most of the processing itself.
Thin client: Almost all business logic is executed on the server, only the result is sent to the client for display; e.g. often seen in Javascript clients running in a web-browser.
Usually people would organize their code differently based on this distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since nobody else dares answer, here are a couple, though I'm not sure they are good examples to go by: (disclaimer: I have only looked into the source code of a few of these)

- [Cube game & 3D engine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cube/), a multiplayer FPS with unique multiplayer editing capabilities, written from scratch using OpenGL and SDL
- [Cube 2: Sauerbraten](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sauerbraten/), same as Cube with slightly more developed features
- [Planeshift](http://www.planeshift.it/), an open-source MMO
- [Red Dwarf Server](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/), a Java server application primarily targeted at online games and MMOs; only comes with small example clients

Comment: Google Web Toolkit puts the client and server in the same project but in different packages, but it enforces client/server separation at compile time. For something where you don't have a fancy custom plugin enforcing this, I think the best option is to have the server include the client so that it has access to client code but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is too late but heres what i have to say about it, i usually keep the server and the client in the same project just incase they both need access to a class. If you are still interested in some example code, ive been doing networking for 5 years+ and i have plenty of example code if youre interested.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, "in case they both need access to a class" is not a definitive reason to put the code in the same project. A project can be a dependency of another project, or can be compiled to a library which the other project includes in its classpath. Especially since you don't want to ship with server code in your client, I think it makes sense to separate them out so that the server project includes the client code but not vice versa, right?

Comment: True, but i like to keep them together untill i release the final product, i would seperate them before i released it to save space because the client doesnt need access to the server classes, but when im developing the program i usually keep them together.

Comment: That seems like it could be difficult, especially if more and more coupling problems are introduced over time and then, come release time, you have a big mess on your hands and have to sift through it and decouple manually. I would prefer immediate, compile-time feedback to deploy-time cleanup, since it should never be the case that the client uses server-specific code. It's definitely a matter of opinion though, and it's likely you have more actual experience with it than I do.

Comment: Well i think its a good idea to keep them in the same project untill you release it because sometimes the server and the client need to share a class, like if you had a checkers game and both the server and the client needed an instance of player to keep track of the pieces each player owned, things like that.